# Python error "import: unable to open X server"

Tags: python

I am getting the following errors when trying to run a piece of python code:

```
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/366.
from: can't read /var/mail/datetime
./mixcloud.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./mixcloud.py: line 3: `now = datetime.now()'
```

The code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta

now = datetime.now()
```

I really lack to see a problem. Is this something that my server is just having a problem with and not the code itself?

Comment: For the record, it works on my computer. Linux Mint 15, python 2.7.5 anaconda.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

those are errors from your command shell.  you are running code through the shell, not python.

try from a python interpreter ;)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta
>>> 
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>>
```

if you are using a script, you may invoke directly with python:

```
$ python mixcloud.py
```

otherwise, ensure it starts with the proper shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

... and then you can invoke it by name alone (assuming it is marked as executable):

```
$ ./mixcloud.py
```

Comment: For a bit more explanation: Just naming a file `something.py` doesn't cause it to be run as Python when you execute `something.py`. Everything that's not a binary (ELF, Mach-O, whatever's appropriate for your platform) is run as with the default shell (usually `/bin/sh something.py`) as an interpreter, unless the first line is a shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/env python`, in which case it will be run with what you specified (`/usr/bin/env python something.py`).

Comment: One more thing: All of this is true for POSIX and POSIX-like systems only—meaning almost every platform you'll ever care about except Windows.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Check whether your **#!** line is in the first line of your python file. I got this error because I put this line into the second line of the file.

Comment: I got this error because I had a space before my `#!`

Comment: aaand I missed out the !

Answer (score 5):

you can add the following line in the top of your python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: I had an issue on my linux pipeline saying that on a file in `node_modules/.bin` : 

```text
1: //: Permission denied
import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/359.`
```

It was indeed the lack of shebang at the top of the bin file that was triggering this - not super explicit - error, thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to run my python script on docker with **docker run**.
Make sure in this case that you set the entry point is set correctly:

```
--entrypoint /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, works well in December 2022.