# Import: unable to open X server

Tags: java, computer-science

I keep getting this in java.
what does this mean
I made my code in the eclipse IDE but am now opening it up in my terminal and keep getting this.

Comment: Please [edit] and show what you enter at the command prompt. For example, are you using `javaw.exe` or `java.exe`?

Comment: Are you by any chance attempting to run a GUI program without a GUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507096/python-error-import-unable-to-open-x-server is the same error but python, are you executing python from java or something like that? The error itself indicates that the current environment has no (access to) the the GUI system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). i.e. it can only print text.

Comment: Check out running Java in headless mode: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html

Comment: Yes but of course that is only appropriate if it is *not* a GUI program

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.